# Переименование файла, если он существует

Tags: c#, .net

подскажите пожалуйста, почему к первому файлу применяется цикл нормально и он сначала с расширением .b,а потом его копирует и получается 2 файла 1.exe и 1.exe.b, а к остальным файлам применяется сразу с .b ? Нужно чтобы сравнивал имена, если такой файл есть ,то в той папке где он есть, ему было дописано в конце ".b". А второй сразу же копируется с расширением "2.b". Цикл While для примера. Нужно чтобы если C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\papka1\1.exe == C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\papka2\1.exe , то в papka2 , файл 1.exe - стал 1.exe.b и скопировался из papka 1 с расширением .ехе - как пример. И так каждый раз при проверке,если файл существует ,то нужен его ренейм *.*.b в papka2.в не зависимости от расширения. Думаю нужно именно через Process и ренейм, так как именно он может реализовать ренейм открытых процессов.

```
        string firstDir = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\papka1";
        string secondDir = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\papka2";
        while (true) { // цикл для примера
            try
            {
                foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(firstDir))
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    string targetPath = Path.Combine(secondDir, fileName);
                    Process process = new Process();
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    if (File.Exists(targetPath)) // если файл уже существует, то в targetPath к файлу дописывается .b
                    {
                        string result = Path.GetFileName(targetPath);
                        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                        startInfo.Arguments = "/C Rename " + " " + targetPath + " " + result + ".b";
                        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                        process.Start();
                    }
                    File.Copy(filePath, targetPath); // копирует файлы во вторую папку ( в этот момент уже дубль файла с дописью .b) 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Пробелы в именах папок/файлов есть? Тогда нужно закавычить путь.

Comment: Зачем здесь Process? Если можно File.Move?

Comment: @aepot я только учусь,хочется разобраться,через File.Move не получилось из-за того что на открытый ехе ругался,что процесс занят и не смог ренейм сделать

Comment: Так открытый exe вы никак не подмените, ни через Move, не через шелл.

Comment: @aepot я не знаю как,но через шелл мне дает это сделать, а через file.move / file.copy пишет что процесс занят,хотя я попробовал руками изменить имя и у меня получилось, WaitForExit помог, я пробовал с process.close(); оказалось все проще чем подразумивалось :) но вам огромное спасибо, вы мне часто помогаете по человечески и объясняете

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov большое спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем здесь `Process`, если можно `File.Move`?

По коду:

1. `startInfo.Arguments = "/C Rename " + targetPath + " " + targetPath + ".b";`
2. `process.Start(); process.WaitForExit();`
3. `string result = Path.GetFileName(targetPath);` вообще бессмыслица, у вас же есть переменная `fileName` готовая, да и не нужна она вам.

Должно получиться что-то такое:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(firstDir))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string targetPath = Path.Combine(secondDir, fileName);
    if (File.Exists(targetPath)) 
    {
        File.Move(targetPath, targetPath + ".b");
    }
    File.Copy(filePath, targetPath);
}
```

Через `Process`

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(firstDir))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string targetPath = Path.Combine(secondDir, fileName);
    if (File.Exists(targetPath)) 
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/C rename " + targetPath + " " + targetPath + ".b",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        }).WaitForExit();
    }
    File.Copy(filePath, targetPath);
}
```